# transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugAndroidTest error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting this weird error, and can't seem to understand what's the problem:

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to
>   process
>   .../Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/19.1.0/support-v4-19.1.0.jar

caused by, caused by, caused by ...

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Type
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentContainer is referenced as an interface
>   from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1`.
>           at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:89)
>           at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:60)
>           at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:64)
>           ... 11 more

Note that I don't even use the v4-19.1.0, I only call:

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it seems the problem was that I was missing some dependencies:

```
androidTestImplementation "com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8"
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.18.3"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"
```

Seemed to solve it.